# How Get distinct value node XML

Tags: xml, xpath, distinct

I am new in XML, so I hope your help.
I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Students> -<Student Id="001">
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <LastName>Kohen</LastName> -<Courses> -<Course Id="01">
                <Name>C#</Name>
            </Course> -<Course Id="02">
                <Name>Java</Name>
            </Course>
        </Courses>
    </Student> -<Student Id="002">
        <Name>Nick</Name>
        <LastName>Nikes</LastName> -<Courses> -<Course Id="02">
                <Name>Java</Name>
            </Course> -<Course Id="03">
                <Name>Oracle</Name>
            </Course>
        </Courses>
    </Student> -<Student Id="003">
        <Name>Rafi</Name>
        <LastName>rafifa</LastName> -<Courses> -<Course Id="02">
                <Name>Java</Name>
            </Course> -<Course Id="03">
                <Name>Oracle</Name>
            </Course>
        </Courses>
    </Student> -<Student Id="004">
        <Name>Yosi</Name>
        <LastName>Koen</LastName> -<Courses> -<Course Id="04">
                <Name>SQL</Name>
            </Course> -<Course Id="03">
                <Name>Oracle</Name>
            </Course>
        </Courses>
    </Student>
</Students>
```

I need know two things:

1. all courses
2. And how many students studing in each course.

Comment: hi, what programming language do you use?

Comment: Could you post your XML as XML code (indent to get code tags). Furthermore you should state what you want to use to get your data, I'm assuming XPath because of your labels, If so, please state that. Also, what have you tried until now?

Answer (score 3):

***A pure*** XPath *1.0*:
Distinct courses:

```
//Course[not(preceding::Course/@Id = @Id)]
```

Answer (score 3):

> I need know two things:
>    1.all courses

**Use**:

```
/*/*/Courses/Course[not(Name = preceding::Course/Name)]
```

> 2.And how many students studing in each course.

**For a given course use**:

```
count(/*/Student[Courses/Course/@Id = $vCourseId])
```

where `$vCourseId` must be substituted with the actual course Id.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/*/Courses/Course[not(Name = preceding::Course/Name)]"/>
     ===============
     <xsl:for-each select=
     "/*/*/Courses/Course[not(Name = preceding::Course/Name)]">

     <xsl:variable name="vCourseId" select="@Id"/>

     Course Id = <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>, Students = <xsl:text/>
     <xsl:value-of select="count(/*/Student[Courses/Course/@Id = $vCourseId])"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Students> -
    <Student Id="001">
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <LastName>Kohen</LastName> -
        <Courses> -
            <Course Id="01">
                <Name>C#</Name>
            </Course> -
            <Course Id="02">
                <Name>Java</Name>
            </Course>
        </Courses>
    </Student> -
    <Student Id="002">
        <Name>Nick</Name>
        <LastName>Nikes</LastName> -
        <Courses> -
            <Course Id="02">
                <Name>Java</Name>
            </Course> -
            <Course Id="03">
                <Name>Oracle</Name>
            </Course>
        </Courses>
    </Student> -
    <Student Id="003">
        <Name>Rafi</Name>
        <LastName>rafifa</LastName> -
        <Courses> -
            <Course Id="02">
                <Name>Java</Name>
            </Course> -
            <Course Id="03">
                <Name>Oracle</Name>
            </Course>
        </Courses>
    </Student> -
    <Student Id="004">
        <Name>Yosi</Name>
        <LastName>Koen</LastName> -
        <Courses> -
            <Course Id="04">
                <Name>SQL</Name>
            </Course> -
            <Course Id="03">
                <Name>Oracle</Name>
            </Course>
        </Courses>
    </Student>
</Students>
```

**the two XPath expressions are evaluated (the second repeatedly for each course) and the results of these evaluations are copied to the output**:

```
<Course Id="01">
   <Name>C#</Name>
</Course>
<Course Id="02">
   <Name>Java</Name>
</Course>
<Course Id="03">
   <Name>Oracle</Name>
</Course>
<Course Id="04">
   <Name>SQL</Name>
</Course>
     ===============


     Course Id = 01, Students = 1

     Course Id = 02, Students = 3

     Course Id = 03, Students = 3

     Course Id = 04, Students = 1
```