# find distinct values from two xml files using php

Tags: php, xml

i have some xml files as follows-

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <contacts>
      <contact>
        <mobile_no>9829344744</mobile_no>
        <name>Sample Name 1</name>
        <email>Some Email</email>
      </contact>
      <contact>
        <mobile_no>9829344799</mobile_no>
        <name>Sample Name 2</name>
        <email>Some Email</email>
      </contact>
      <contact>
        <mobile_no>9829345035</mobile_no>
        <name>Sample Name 3</name>
        <email>Some Email</email>
      </contact>
</contacts>
```

i have two xml files in above format. each file has distinct `<mobile_no>`
but i want to extract distinct `<mobile_no>` from both files.

i have tried and use following code of php

```
$arr_filename[] = "file1.xml";
$arr_filename[] = "file2.xml";

$arr_contact = array();

foreach($arr_filename as $filename)
{
    $xml = new simpleXMLElement($filename, null, true);
    $contact_array1 = $xml->xpath('contact/mobile_no');

    for($i=0; $i<count($contact_array1); $i++)
    {
        $arr_contact[$contact_array1[$i]]=true;
    }
}
```

i found array `$arr_contact` with distinct contact no as its key
its working fine but problem is that when files has large content(records) and use more files (approximately 10) it takes too much time to process. i want to get more efficient method to extract distinct mobile no from more than one xml files. just as we extract distinct from more than one table in mysql.

Comment: You can try to [merge the xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163675/merge-xml-files-in-php) files first and then read them. Should be faster.

Comment: Instead of your method please try it. It will help you "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341305/how-get-distinct-value-node-xml"

Comment: @DainisAbols thanks bro i can merge but how distinct mobile_no in new merged file.

Comment: You can use [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique) after the final array is created.

Comment: @DainisAbols i don't want to use array because may be there a lacs of records. it use memory a lot.

Comment: `$arr_contact[$contact_array1[$i]]=true;` you are using an array already...

Comment: @DainisAbols yes thats why i put question here i can't use array. ok one more thing can we read xml file node by node without using array.

Comment: How do you want to process the numbers? Where do you want to store them? What is your desired end result?

Comment: @DainisAbols i am storing contacts in xml files and get distinct. i am using mysql db already but there is a large no of records and found slow process when operating on some conditions. so the main thing is that reduce processing time to extract mobile no with some condtions. so i decided to use xml files to store contacts. its ok. now only thing is remaining is thant extract distinct mobile no from more than one file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44612/discussion-between-dainis-abols-and-satish-sharma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, first merge:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x1); // assume XML in $x1 and $x2
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($x2);

// merge $xml2 into $xml
foreach ($xml2->contact as $contact) {
    $newcontact = $xml->addChild("contact");
    foreach ($contact->children() as $name => $value)
        $newcontact->addChild($name, $value);
}

unset($xml2); // dispose $xml2
```

then select:

```
// use xpath to select <contact> with distinct contact/mobile_no 
$results = $xml->xpath("/contacts/contact[not(mobile_no = following::mobile_no)]");
var_dump($results);
```

see it working: https://eval.in/86352